# cx_Freeze doesn't want to apply icon to .exe file

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I want to compile a python script using the cx_Freeze module. For this I write the following `setup.py` file:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

executables = Executable(script = "Example5.py",icon = "icon.ico")
zip_include_packages = ["collections", "importlib", "encodings"]
excludes = [
    'unicodedata', 'logging', 'unittest', 'email', 'html', 'http', 'urllib',
    'bz2'
]

options = {
    "build_exe": {
        "include_msvcr": True,
        "excludes": excludes,
        "zip_include_packages":zip_include_packages,
        "build_exe": "Test compiling",
    }
}

setup(
    name='Test',
    version='1.0.0',
    description='Testing compile',
    executables=[executables],
    options=options
)
```

This script doesn't want to compile, cx_Freeze is failing with error:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initalize: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
Current thread 0x00000bf4 (most recent call first)
```

But if I replace this line:

```
executables = Executable(script = "Example5.py",icon = "icon.ico")
```

by:

```
executables = Executable(script = "Example5.py")
```

the script is working and creates a .exe file.
I don't understand why the icon is not set.
Source code: https://github.com/Bus-Artyom/Test_compile
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `icon.ico` is not a valid `.ico` file (but rather a `.png` file which has been renamed to `.ico`?).

Try with a valid `.ico` file.